# How to access an existing database file through html5?

Tags: html

I'm working on an desktop app(hta) that need to access information from a database.
My challenge is that already I have the data I need in a sqlite database file. I just want to access this database file from my app then manipulate and display the results to the users.Is it possible to deploy an app like this? I'm not finding a way to access an existing database file through html5.(The sqlite database file will be created during the app installation.It is present in C:\filepath)

Comment: Html is just a markup language. You will need something like javascript to do some magic with parsing and stuff. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to access the database using openDatabase() method of html5.. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution will depend on your use case. I can see two of them.

**1. Your application runs in disconnected mode (standalone)**

HTML5 provides an API called [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). It enables you to access an API for storage in the web browser. It's pretty much build around SQLite features. However, [all the web browsers do not support it.](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20sql)

**2. Your application can access a remote server**

In the case you have a remote database, and your application is allowed to access it, I would suggest that you connect to your database by making requests to it. Of course, you will require to develop your own little API on the server side to access the database e.g. via XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to access Web SQL databases. Remember, Web SQL is deprecated and only supported in Chrome and Safari. And Web SQL isn’t even actually part of the HTML5 specification.

For a starter's guide: [HTML5 Doctor: Introduction to Web SQL Databases](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/)